# How do I set up usbip on 18.04 and avoid the error "usbip: error: recv op_common"?

Tags: networking, usb, 18.04

After issuing

```
sudo usbip attach -r 10.17.28.5 -b 1.1-3
```

I receive the messages

```
usbip: error: recv op_common  
usbip: error: query
```

What would be the next step?

Specifically, I have an APC 850 connected via USB to an LG network storage device that exports the USB via usbip. I want to access it over the network with my laptop that runs 18.04.01, but the most that happens is the communication is immediately lost.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more context? What do you want to achieve? What’s the USB device in question? Did you perform any other actions to set it or its connection up? Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))